# Vvertical offset % function to a SMA

Tags: range, pine-script, offset, tradingview-api, moving-average

is it possible to add a vertical offset in % function to a SMA?

My aim is to attach this SMA to a 1 period ATR.

Thanks

I'm not good with coding so I tried to use already existent indicators, which don't work.
I tried to modify already existent codes but I cannot achieve what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate your SMA and add 1% to its value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

offset = input.int(1, "Offset [%]") * 0.01

sma_val = ta.sma(close, 9)
sma_offset_val = sma_val * (1 + offset)

plot(sma_val, "SMA", color.green)
plot(sma_offset_val, "SMA Offset", color.red)
```

[image]